# How to find out the POST request parameters using postman?

Tags: postman

I want to automate document retrieval from a specific website.

1-I need to send a request (GET) to the site.

2-Then submit a filled form (POST).

3-Then obtain all the files (multiple GETS?)

4-Then repeat again using new form information.

Is this all possible with POSTMAN? are there tools better suited for this job?

Answer (score 0):

You can order those requests in a folder and use **Collection Runner** to automate the requests. The postman will run those requests in the order you have aligned the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Postman is made to make requests.
To "find out the POST request", you need to use another tool to identify these calls, like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (free), or the Debuging/developer tools of any major browsers.